# different value e.target in browers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mozilla

I want to know why Mozilla and Chrome have other value of e.target. 
I prepared this example for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/qdthnmdx/

In the Mozilla e.target has value:

```
<button type="button">
```

But in the Chrome this is:

```
<span>Sometext</span>
```

Is it some bug?

Comment: Show the code in your question, not in a JS Fiddle. Stackoverflow provides the same functionality in snipplets. The last button in the toolbar when you are writing your question.

Comment: IIRC by specs, click events should be blocked by the button element. FF would follow the specs and not chrome. This is a known discrepancy between both UAs, but I can't find anymore where I read that... Also, I may not remember correctly at all.

Comment: @epascarello, about the dupe, while it definitely gives a good explanation about the difference between e.target and e.currentTarget, there is also something special about the `<button>` element, so that FF doesn't set `target` to the inner elements. If we [replace this button with a `<div>`](https://jsfiddle.net/qdthnmdx/2/) then both UAs have the same behavior.  FF even has an `explicitOriginalTarget`property which goes until the exact TextNode that has been clicked. In the case of `<button>`, it still stops at the button... Not sure it's worth a reopening though...

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that every browser have their own implementation of the specificacion from JavaScript, here i have diferent result of your code for you even on Internet explore and google Chrone exist difference:

IE 11:
[image]

Google Chrome:
[image]

For more clarification in what is ECMA Specs is see: 
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Answer (score -1):

event.target is not different in browsers.

event.target is a reference to the object that dispatched the event.
as you are attaching to the button,it is also attached to span element too.
so when you hit on span,it is showing span node and on button it is showing button which is right, but this behaviour is more obvious on chrome but not on mozilla.

If you just want to attach an event on the button element. you can consider doing as the following

If you want button to be displayed on both button and span click , you might consider of using currentTarget here.

currentTarget always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached.

I guess it could be useful here.

check this snippet

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.nodeName);
});
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: 0;
  padding:10px;
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="id-div">
  <button type="button">
    <span>Sometext</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am guessing you did not click directly on the red box in chrome... no alert. That is what the OP is talking about. Clicking on the span means the target is the span, not the button.