# JavaScript ActiveElement is form not button with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a list of forms on my site with JS/AJAX that submits the forms on click.  The JavaScript determines the submit type based on the active element.  This has been working find across multiple browser.

Problem:  Basically Safari (Version 10.0.2) on MAC considers the activeElement the form instead of the button so the getAttribute returns null.  Is there a way to get the clicked element?  I need to know which button the user clicked.

HTML Stuff:

```
<div id="#Records">
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  ...
  <input name="submit" type="submit" data-action="send" value="send stuff" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" data-action="update" value="update" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" data-action="delete" value="delete" />
</form>
</div>
```

JavaScript stuff

```
    $("#Records form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.action;
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        var action = document.activeElement.getAttribute('data-action');
        data.push({ name: 'submit', value: action });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            url: url
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#Records").html(data);
        }).fail(function (result) {
            ShowMessage("Error updating record!");
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Don't use multiple submit buttons. Use button buttons instead.

Comment: Probably related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841688/different-value-e-target-in-browers, (check the comments below the question), FF doesn't set the `activeElement` at all (it keeps body). But @TinyGiant is right, don't use submit buttons here, as you have no *no-script* fallback, it doesn't make sense to use `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get the element using e.currentTarget instead of the active element? Something like

```
var action = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-action');
```

(I'm assuming button click leads to the submit)

Comment: $(e.currentTarget) is the form and since the form does not have that attribute it will not work.  Same problem basically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on Tiny Giant and other comments I have changed the code to this.  Not sure it is the best method but seems to work everywhere I have tested.

note simplified, comments welcome

HTML

```
<div id="#Records">
 <form action="update.php" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="button" onclick="return $(this).processRequest(this, 'send');" data-action="send" value="send stuff" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return $(this).processRequest(this, 'update');" data-action="update" value="update" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return $(this).processRequest(this, 'delete');" data-action="delete" value="delete" />
 </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery.fn.processRequest =
function(button, action)
{
    var form = $(button).parents('form');
    var url = form[0].action;
    var data = $(form).serializeArray()
    data.push({ name: 'submit', value: action });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        url: url
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#Records").html(data);
    }).fail(function (result) {
        ShowMessage("Error updating record!");
    });

    return false;
}
```